# Settings or something on Nouveau driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 15.04, nouveau

I'm on Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 and Nouveau driver is set by default. I don't want to set Nvidia proprietary driver because of my little fear (I broke my pc a while ago on 14.04 only trying to set it on "additional drivers" menu, a plague to restore it on recovery terminal).

Then, Nouveau isn't that shame, so I don't need to change driver, but it hasn't got any graphic settings or something like `nvidia-settings`. I only use the command `xgamma -gamma n` for gamma settings because my display is really too bright.

Can I do something? Is there any application or tweak?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my laptop:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

then

```
xbacklight -set 80
```

This set my brightness to 80%. You could find a good value then add the "xbacklight -set xx" code to your startup session commands? That would set a value on logon you liked.

Kind regards,
Pete